# How to get the last version of Ekiga?

Tags: software-center, versions, ekiga

Ubuntu Software Center currently provides only version 3.2.6 of Ekiga, but that is outdated. Is there a way to have it updated?

Answer (score 2):

Given that you say only 3.2.6 is available, it must mean that you are on Ubuntu 10.04, which for the desktop version, will be End of Life in approximately one month.

Ekiga is distributed in the Ubuntu archives, and there are newer versions available on newer versions of Ubuntu. You should upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu to get them. Version 3.3.7 is available on Ubuntu 12.04 for example.

You can see what version of Ekiga is in what version of Ubuntu, [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ekiga).

Comment: Can he not install those deb file?

Comment: Ok tnx, although it sounds somewhat disturbing... I'm using easypeasy on a netbook. What does this End of Life mean exactly? and are there any working newer versions? (I tried Bodhi and Xubuntu, but unacceptably low performance)

Comment: [This](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#End_of_Life_.28EOL.29) is a list with the EOL versions by now.

Comment: @Thomas15v Probably not. Dependencies would have changed. Would end up pulling in most of the distribution anyway.

Comment: @d3553 EOL means that it will no longer be supported. It's also quite old. I don't know what easypeasy is, but if it's not an official Ubuntu derivative (like Kubuntu is), then it also makes your question off topic for Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: easypeasy used to be called Ubuntu Eee. Maybe that helps?

Comment: I don't think it's an official derivative. But either way it sounds like it's based on Ubuntu 10.04, which is 3 years old now.